# How to add app_label in Custom Auth User Model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Following code snippet I have tried but did not work for me

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
 class Meta:
   app_label = 'apis'
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be misplaced - `app_label` is placed with a Django app in the `urls.py` file to namespace the templates within the app.

If you have an app called `users` with a `users/models.py` file containing:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
```

Then you could make a sibling file for your user routes called `users/urls.py`, and include:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views ListUserView

app_name = "users"

urlpatterns = [
    path("list/", ListUserView.as_view(), name="list"),
]
```

Then you could access this route in your templates by using `{% url 'users:list' %}`, for example. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I want to define model outside app scope

Comment: In my time working with Django, I’ve never defined a model outside of an app. Why are you trying to do this? Where would the migrations for the model be created? The underlying tables for Django models are also created as `appname_modelname`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this goes against everything I've seen in my years using Django. It's possible I'm missing something, but you may want to reconsider your app structure. Good luck.

Comment: It is possible to declare models outside django app using app_label but I am unable to add app_label for abstract model. It is working for non abstract models

Comment: Abstract models must be inherited into a model within an app to be used, which is where it will receive migrations, and an associated `app_label`.

Comment: Did not get this. Can you please give an example?

Comment: The documentation has good explanations: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes You can created an abstract class for a model containing, for example, shared fields. However, the models that inherit those fields are created within an app. No database table is created for the abstract class itself, just the models that inherit from the abstract class within an app.